# Swift AVPlayerLayer videoGravity .resizeAspect only respects height not width

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I have an AVPlayer and AVPlayerLayer embedded in a simple UIView. This plays the movie but adjusting `playerLayer.videoGravity` only effects the movies relative height:

1. `.resizeAspect` fills all the way to side of the `videoview` UIView and crops the height
2. `.resizeAspectFill` looks like a zoomed in version of the stretched `.resizeAspect`

```
    var player = AVPlayer()
    @IBOutlet weak var videoview: UIView!
```

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
                
        playerLayer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat((-90 * Double.pi)/180)))
                                       
        playerLayer.frame = videoview.bounds
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect

        videoview.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)     
        
        player.play()
    }
```

Comment: you want to fix your video to Devices width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was with `playerLayer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat((-90 * Double.pi)/180)))` and the video/image size. The wrong height/width were used previously (and needed to be transposed). This resolved the issue.